# Application: Sum of Digits

Tags: summation, real-numbers, square-numbers, divisor-sum, word-problem

if a five digit number N is such that sum of its digit is 29, can N be square of an integer?

Suppose N be abcde, where a+b+c+d+e = 29. Can square of any number less than abcde is equal to abcde itself.

Completely struck on how to start solving.

Comment: An answer was just deleted although a simple edit would have made it right. Squares are $0,1,4,7$ modulo $9$ and the required number is $2$ modulo $9$.

Answer (score 0):

No. The number is 2 modulo 9 (because 29 is), and squares can only have remainder 0,1,4 or 7 modulo 9 (squares of 0 to 8 reduced modulo 9). Number of digits is not needed.

Comment: If squares are $0,2,4,7$ modulo $9$ and the number is $2$ modulo $9$, why can it be no square ?